# How to insert an element to alist in a vector of lists in C++?

Tags: c++, list, vector, constructor

I'm trying to create a vector of lists and then insert an element to a specific list in the vector.
That what I was trying to do

```
vector<list<int>> depth_lists;
depth_lists[0].push_back(1);
```

It fails with some very long exit code... What am I doing wrong here? I think I maybe had to somehow initialize each list in the vector of lists before inserting elements to it but doesn't the constructor of the vector do it for me?

Comment: `vector<list<int>> depth_lists;` defines a `vector` with no elements in it. That means there is no `depth_lists[0]` to `push_back` into. `vector<list<int>> depth_lists(10);` would make a `vector` with 10 `list`s. Change 10 to suit your needs. If you don't know your needs, you can `push_back` into the `vector` just like you do with the `list`s in the `vector`

Comment: Side note about the very long exit code. Take the number and convert it to hexadecimal. They are usually more recognizable and easily looked up with a websearch. Sometimes the hex version spells out words that practically tell you what went wrong. Well, not DEADBEEF, we're not programming cows, but when you see something like that, you can be pretty sure the program is trying to tell you something important.

Comment: @user4581301 Please turn that into an answer.

Comment: This question is asked a couple times a week. I was off looking for a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an empty vector

```
vector<list<int>> depth_lists;
```

So you may not use the subscript operator

```
depth_lists[0].push_back(1);
```

You could write for example

```
 depth_lists.push_back( { 1 } );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::list<int>> v;
    
    v.push_back( { 1 } );
    
    v[0].push_back( 2 );
    
    for ( const auto &lst : v )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : lst )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a list with a single one, you can use `std::list`'s [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list) that takes a count and a value, and just [emplace it to the back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) of the `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> depth_lists;
depth_lists.emplace_back(1ul,1);
```